# Can I use a locally declared enum class as template non-type parameter? (gcc gives obscure error)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

The following code fails to compile in gcc 4.8.1 thru 6.3:

```
#include <cassert>

template<typename T, T X>
struct Mode {
    using type = Mode;
    using value_type = T;
    static constexpr value_type value = X;
```

> ```
> ^^^ error: 'constexpr const value_type Mode<main()::TestEnum, (main::TestEnum)0>::value', declared using local type 'const value_type {aka const main()::TestEnum}', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
> ```

```
    constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept { return value; }
};

int main()
{
    enum class TestEnum { test1, test2 };
    constexpr Mode<TestEnum, TestEnum::test1> test1 = {};
    constexpr Mode<TestEnum, TestEnum::test2> test2 = {};

    assert(static_cast<TestEnum>(test1) == TestEnum::test1);
}
```

clang 3.9.1 and MSVC 2015 SP3 compile it without error.

If I move `enum class TestEnum { test1, test2 };` into the global scope then it compiles without error.

Is the code legal? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would say a GCC bug up to v6.x. GCC 7 compiles it.

Comment: @skypjack What's your GCC version? GCC 7 at godbolt.org gives the same error: https://godbolt.org/g/YIH3JD

Comment: Tried it on [melpon](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gL4cjBjD40r7peh5).

Comment: @skpjack, Can you post a link to GCC 7 please? Finding up to 6.3 online. Thx.

Comment: @skypjack [GCC 7 does not compile it if you use e.g. `-std=c++14`.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8xiqSCYUnoLZOMKN)

Comment: @cpplearner Oh, you're right, I didn't see it was set to C++1z. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you still have to define `Mode::value`, as the compiler says (ODR). If I am not mistaken, this changes with C++17 and the definition is not mandatory any more, which explains why it runs with the `std=c++1z` flag.

This compiles and runs also "before" `std=c++1z`:

```
#include <cassert>

template<typename T, T X>
struct Mode {
    using type = Mode;
    using value_type = T;
    static constexpr value_type value = X;

    constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept { return value; }
};

template<typename T, T X> constexpr T Mode<T,X>::value;

int main()
{
    enum class TestEnum { test1, test2 };
    constexpr Mode<TestEnum, TestEnum::test1> test1 = {};
    //constexpr Mode<TestEnum, TestEnum::test2> test2 = {};

    assert(static_cast<TestEnum>(test1) == TestEnum::test1);
}
```

You can [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2900be8d91690185).